# Why transport layer's order is lower than application layer's order

Tags: tcp

In network communication, the first thing that is made by sender is to establish a tcp connection or udp connection. After tcp or udp connection is established successfully, it is time to application layer to send packets to the destination.

So why does the order of transport layer come after the application layer in osi model? In the context of osi model, as if the application layer process is the first thing that will done by receiver machine.

Thank you very much

Comment: "So why the order of transport layer comes after the application layer in OSI model?": it doesn't. Check your facts. And the OSI model doesn't apply to TCP/IP; but the TCP/IP layer model does; and it also has the transport layer lower than the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the transport (4th) layer does not come after the application (7th) layer in the ISO-OSI model. You can verify that f.e. by looking at [OSI model on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

I guess that your confusion comes from pictures all around the internet. The application layer is usually on the first line, at the top of an OSI stack. But that means that it is the last - or highest - layer, not the first.

The relationship between neighbouring layers is, that the lower layer *encapsulates* the data from the higher layer by adding a header before it. I can recommend [this article on that](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/data-encapsulation-and-de-encapsulation-explained.html) or search for *data encapsulation OSI model* for yourself, there is plenty of cool images and articles explaining that.

If you'd have any further questions, or wanted some clarification, feel free to edit your question and notify me in the comment.